# Attempt at problem that uses property of linear transformations acting on bases

Tags: linear-algebra

I have seen the solution to this problem and want to know if it is the best approach.Give an example of a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ such that null$T$=range$T$

Proof:Let $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$ be the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^4$

define a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$

as follows $T(e_1)=0,T(e_2)=0,T(e_3)=e_1,T(e_4)=e_2$

Thus null$T$=span$(e_1,e_2)$, range$T$=span$(e_1,e_2)$

Hence null$T$=range$T$

Is this the best way to approach this problem?Would this answer be complete or completely right?Are there better alternatives to approach this problem?Also, would I need to express a vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors and apply the transformation to the basis vectors to show the linear extension to $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: Since you seem very determined to give the “best” possible answer, you might find it more efficient to write out the matrix of your transformation (rather than explicitly writing what $T$ does to each basis vector)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  Im trying to avoid matrices here since this is in Axler's book Linear algebra done right. The exercise is given before matrices are introduced.Ive tried to make a proof for this in the comment below.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks for an example of a linear transformation satisfying some conditions, and the solution constructs such a linear transformation.

You seem to be uncertain about whether the map they define is indeed a linear transformation $\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^4$. Indeed, if you know how a linear map is defined on a basis of its domain (e.g., $T(e_1), T(e_2), T(e_3), T(e_4)$), then you have completely specified the linear map. One way to justify this claim is what you suggested: any vector in $\mathbb{R}^4$ can be written as $c_1 e_1 + \cdots + c_4 e_4$ for some $c_i$, and then $T(c_1 e_1 + \cdots + c_4 e_4) = c_1 T(e_1) + \cdots + c_4 T(e_4)$. Another way to justify the claim is to note that knowing $T(e_1),\ldots, T(e_4)$ gives you the four columns of the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $\{e_1, \ldots, e_4\}$.

Comment: would the answer that I showed be given full credit if it were a solution to an exam. Is it thorough enough?

Comment: Typically, on problems that ask you to produce examples like this one, you are not expected to prove that your example is valid. That being said, different instructors have different tastes so your teacher’s standards may be different

Comment: If I wanted to turn the solution into a proof is this sufficient let $v \in \mathbb{R}^4$ then there exists scalars $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4$ such that $v=c_{1}e_{1}+c_e_{2}+c_{3}e_{3}+c_{4}e_{4}$ then $Tv=c_3e_1+c_4e_4$?

Comment: I don’t see how your comment comes any closer to proving that the kernel and range are what they’re supposed to be